# how to config activemq using jdbc message store without deleting the message after comsumed?

Tags: jdbc, activemq-classic

As we know, the message will be deleted by activemq after the message comsumed succeed. i want to stroe the message in the database forever. how to config the activemq?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the most obvious way to do that is to read the message in, process it and then move it to an archive queue.

If you really want to store the message on the queue you are reading from (for whatever reason), you can avoid consume the message using a `QueueBrowser` instead of `receive`.

Check out [this Oracle JMS example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncfl/index.html) on the topic, it should work for ActiveMQ/JMS as well.

Another way, just to mention it, is to read it in a transaction, then roll back the transaction once done. The downside is that you will be trying to read the same message over and over and over and..